# What should be the priority to answer questions tagged with both [jquery] and [javascript]?

Tags: discussion

Lately, there have been numerous questions being asked on SO, with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript),[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) both tagged.

For example consider this case : User wants to hide an element.

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.display="none";
```

jQuery :

```
$('#divId').hide()
```

Some might accept the second as it seems easy to understand and implement.

Almost every question has an answer in both plain old javascript and modern jQuery. But if a user has the whole project with 1000 lines of plain javascript code, is it advisable to use jQuery in such cases?

What should an answering person take as priority :

1. The order in which the tags are used? (So, if javascript is tagged first, answer should be in javascript)
2. The most optimized way to solve the problem.
3. The language currently used.

Comment: jQuery is still Javascript. I don't understand why people keep thinking it is a new language. and if the question is tagged with [jquery], give jQuery solution, and it is still a Javascript solution (with jQuery dependency). you can add non-jquery solution for completeness if you want.

Comment: @BryanChen I know jQuery is still Javascript, but if the current code is in pure javascript, what should be the answer based on?

Comment: if the question is tagged with [jquery], OP probably accept jquery answer. if OP don't want jquery, [jquery] tag should be removed.

Comment: @BryanChen You have the answer. Please post it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), the OP will probably accept jQuery answer. However, you can add extra non-jquery solution for completeness if you want.

If OP doesn't want jQuery, then the question shouldn't be tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).