# Is there a rule for tag priority - ordering

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a rule or a formulation on how I put tags on a question and what is the meaning of them ?
Also
When you are viewing questions for a specific tag is the ordering taken into account?

For example there is a  (hypothetical) question talking about a problem on a wordpress functionality, the user tags it as [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) , [a specific to problem tag], [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). Reading the question you can understand that is more a wordpress configuration problem than a php.

Should I re-arrange the tags? If I do it, does it have a meaning for anyone except myself? 
If this does not exist, is anyone else interest in this 'feature'

As a user when I am reading question to answer or find an answer, I am taking into account the tag ordering, meaning that the first tag is more relevant that the other.

Slightly similar question are:

1. [What should be the priority to answer questions tagged with both [jquery] and [javascript]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261621/what-should-be-the-priority-to-answer-questions-tagged-with-both-jquery-and-j)
2. [In what order do tags appear on a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253269/in-what-order-do-tags-appear-on-a-question)

Comment: Isn't your question answered by [In what order do tags appear on a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253269/1288) Tags are ordered automatically.

Comment: Partially, again is a matter of timing and popularity, it does not reflect the actual problem / question. I am also asking in order to see if anyone is interested on adding a feature like this